# How does the water drain out of Girdlegard (das verborgene Land) in Markus Heitz's The Dwarves (Die Zwerge)?

Tags: the-dwarves

Given that the land is surrounded in all directions by mountains, surely the runoff would fill up the land into a big lake, which would have to drain off at the lowest point in the mountains?